# How can I add a script to a gatsby page that runs on every page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, gatsby

I'm trying to add a custom masonry script to a single page in Gatsby. It makes modifications to styling properties of `<div>` elements in a grid layout, but it essentially the script needs to do its thing every time the page is loaded or resized.

The way I'm trying to accomplish this is via requiring the script in an effect hook in a function returning a React component:

```
// in 'page.js'
export default () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        require('./scripts/masonry');
    }

    return // blah blah blah...
}
```

And in the script, I've put all the things I need the script to do in a function called `resizeAll` and attached it to `window.onloadend` and added it to a resize event listener:

```
// in the masonry script at the very bottom
window.onloadend = resizeAll;
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeAll);
```

But this doesn't work because the script seems to run only when the page is resized, but not when loading or navigating to the page. My suspicion is that `window.onloadend` is for some reason broken or clobbered by gatsby's functionality, or that I'm not using it right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **React Helmet** which basically writes things into your html pages `<head>` tag. Also you will need Gatsby's `withPrefix` for resolving the path to the script which comes built-in with Gatsby.

Most likley the Gatsby starter you are using has **React Helmet** already setup (look at your `package.json`). If this is the case simply put your script in the `/static/` folder for your project and then in React include the script into the `<head>` of your page like this:

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { withPrefix } from "gatsby";

<Helmet>
<script src={withPrefix('masonry.js')} />
</Helmet>
```

If for some reason your Gatsby project doesn't already have React Helmet setup then you can setup by following the instructctions [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-eight/#add-page-metadata).

Comment: hanks for your answer! I tried this, and it looks like it exhibits the same behavior where the script doesn't run on page loads.

Comment: Include the script, the problem probably lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I solved the problem! Hooks didn't seem to be doing the trick, so I stuck the `resizeAll` function in the onRouteUpdate export in `gatsby-browser`.

Like Ferran Buireu said, this is a workaround, but my site is pretty small and so far I haven't noticed any severe detriment to performance, but I will rebuild the script later if need be...